# Figure out if <html> contains a keyword

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to figure out how to find out if the opening `<html>` tag of my document has a specific keyword with Python. I'm using urllib and lxml for another part of this application, so I'm trying to achieve it with this.

What I have right now:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from lxml import etree

def get_amp_path(url):
  document = urlopen(url).read()
  tree = etree.HTML(document)
  html = tree.xpath('//html')
  for tag in html:
    print etree.tostring(tag)

  return
```

What I want to do is return true or false if the opening `<html>` tag contains the amp keyword, like so `<html lang="en" amp>`

Right now it seems to print the entire contents of the html tags, not just the attributes. How do I make this more specific?

Comment: Check `tree.attrib`; you don't need the `xpath` lookup since `html` should be the root element already.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`etree.tostring()` simply prints the contents of the node, which at the root level will be the entire HTML. You can check `.attrib` on an element to see the full attribute dictionary, or use `.keys()` to get a list of keys.

Also, since `html` should already be the root element, you don't really need to do an `xpath` lookup.

Something like this should work, assuming you just want to know whether or not it's present:

```
def html_has_amp(url):
    doc = urlopen(url).read()
    tree = etree.HTML(doc)
    return 'amp' in tree.keys()
```